# Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined with --prod and sourceMap as false

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular8

I have Angular8 App and node v12.7.5.
while building Application with --prod and kept sourceMap as false getting the following error on browser console.

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: __dirname is not defined
    at Object.vbkW (main-latest.47e5c88c97278e97cfa4.js:1)
    at n (runtime-latest.9987869375411e01bae9.js:1)
    at Object.jvm8 (main-latest.47e5c88c97278e97cfa4.js:1)
    at n (runtime-latest.9987869375411e01bae9.js:1)
    at Object.R+8r (main-latest.47e5c88c97278e97cfa4.js:1)
    at n (runtime-latest.9987869375411e01bae9.js:1)
    at Object.J4hL (main-latest.47e5c88c97278e97cfa4.js:1)
    at n (runtime-latest.9987869375411e01bae9.js:1)
    at Module.QqbR (main-latest.47e5c88c97278e97cfa4.js:1)
    at n (runtime-latest.9987869375411e01bae9.js:1)
```

If i kept sourceMap as true with --prod build no error.

But i want to build code with --prod and sourceMap as false.
Not able to debug and findout what is the cause behind this error.

Any help is very appricated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: try to create the `index.d.ts` file in the root of your project and add `declare const __dirname: string`. Let me know if it works

Comment: Thanks for reply. Actually problem was there in my case electron version....so i got solution by upgrading electron package version.